# jQuery How to use a ID grabbed from a clicked div

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

[image]I have a people section on a website I'm building which uses isotope for filtering. When I click on a person I want to show their full info on the right. When the click happens I grab the id and store it as a variable. I then have variables named to match up with the grabbed IDs.

How do I use the grabbed ID to target the variables stored in my js file? Currently it only prints out the ID grabbed from the clicked div.

```
var userOne = "<p>userOne info<p>";
var userTwo = "<p>userTwo info<p>";
var userThree = "<p>userThree info<p>";    

$('.item').on("click", function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id'); // this grabs the ID of the div eg userOne
var printId = id; //trying to change the variable so I can use it
$('.bio').html(printID); //this is where it should print out
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access a variable name like that, instead what you can do is to access a object's property with a dynamic key

Assuming the variables `userOne/userTwo` are in the global scope, you can use the bracket notation like

```
var userOne = "<p>userOne info<p>";
var userTwo = "<p>userTwo info<p>";
var userThree = "<p>userThree info<p>";

$('.item').on("click", function () {
    var printId = window[this.id];
    $('.bio').html(printID);
});
```

---

another option is to store those values as properties of an object

```
var user = {
    userOne: "<p>userOne info<p>",
    userTwo: "<p>userTwo info<p>",
    userThree: "<p>userThree info<p>"
};

$('.item').on("click", function () {
    var printId = user[this.id];
    $('.bio').html(printID);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

html

```
<div class="item" data-user="<p>userOne info<p>"></div>
```

js

```
$(".item").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".bio").html($(this).data("user"))
})
```

```js
$(".item").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".bio").html($(this).data("user"))
})
```

```css
div:not(.bio) {
  border:1px dotted grey;
  width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" data-user="<p>userOne info<p>">1</div><br />
<div class="item" data-user="<p>userTwo info<p>">2</div><br />
<div class="item" data-user="<p>userThree info<p>">3</div><br />
<div class="bio"></div>
```